# Java code to access DB from LAN

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, wamp

I installed WampServer in a system 192.168.1.180. How can I access that DB from another computer? (eg; 2nd System: 192.168.1.165)

Is it possible to access it by just change

```
DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB_name ";
```

To

```
DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql:// 192.168.1.180/DB_name";
```

Comment: Depends on the driver.  Try.  Do not add spaces.

Comment: I did it. But..failed

Comment: First thing you need to learn is to understand that "failed" is many, many things, and _you_ are the only one who can explain to us what went wrong.  If you get an error message, show it.  If you get a stack trace, show it.   If you do not explain well enough, your question will be closed.

Comment: I got an error msg like: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Le h�te 'Arjun' n'est pas authoris� � se connecter � ce serveur MySQL"

Comment: MySQL is not correctly configured for external access.  Fix that.  If you need help doing that, consider asking on superusers instead.

Comment: Make sure the port being used in MySQL is given an exemption in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well access a DB from from another computer provided you have the ip address and the other parameters such as the username and password correct. Just remove the spaces after '//' and properly configure your driver. You have to allow incoming connections for port 3306(in case you are using mysql) on other machine's firewall.

Changing firewall settings now depends on the OS you are using. For windows you can look for incoming connections under windows help. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

you just write

```
DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://<pc-name>/Db_name,User,password";
```

and allows MySQL to System firewall, then you will access the another pc MySQL.